# UART is garbled when running at more than 9600 bps

Tags: c, uart, msp430, max3232

I'm connecting 2 [MSP430F5529](http://www.ti.com/product/msp430f5529)-based boards (running at 1 MHz) using UART and [MAX3232](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf) (MSP430F5529 -> MAX3232 -> cable, a few cm long - will be longer in our final application -> MAX3232 -> MSP430F5529).

It works as long as the bit rate of the UART is under 9600 bps. If this is raised, I start getting many errors (usually the MSB is flipped).

If I remove the MAX3232 and connect the boards directly, the problem goes away. It doesn't happen if I loopback, too.

I am running the MAX3232 at 3 V, which the datasheet says is enough:

> Transmitter outputs will meet EIA/TIA-562 levels of ±3.7V with supply voltages as low as 2.7V.

What am I doing wrong?

My code on the TX side is:

```
void UART_Initialize() {

    UCA1CTL1 |= UCSWRST;
    UCA1CTL0 = UCMODE_0; // UART
    UCA1CTL0 &= ~UC7BIT ; // 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit
    UCA1CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2; // Source 1 MHz


    UCA1BR0 = 104; // 104 ~= 9600 bps 
    UCA1BR1 = 0;  

    UCA1MCTL |= UCBRS_0 + UCBRF_0; // Modulation
    P4SEL |= BIT4 + BIT5;
    UCA1CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;
    UCA1IE |= UCRXIE;
}


void UART_send_data(unsigned char character) {
    while (!(UCA1IFG & UCTXIFG));
    UCA1TXBUF = character;
}

unsigned char UART_get_char() {
    while (!(UCA1IFG & UCRXIFG));
    return UCA1RXBUF;
}

void UART_shutdown() {
    UCA1IE &= ~(UCRXIE|UCTXIE);
    UCA1CTL1 = UCSWRST;
}


int main() {
    unsigned char received_data;

    P4OUT = 0x00;
    // Disables the watchdog
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;

    // CPU clock to 1 MHz

    UCSCTL0 = 0x00;
    UCSCTL1 = DCORSEL_3;  
    UCSCTL2 = FLLN5_L;

    __enable_interrupt();
    UART_Initialize();

    while(1) UART_send_data(0x55);

}
```

On the RX side the code is similar except for `main()` (which just receives the value and compares to `0x55`).

Comment: I suppose you're sure your MAX3232s aren't broken? :)

Comment: This was the first thing I thought; I tried a few different MAX3232s and the problem continued.

Comment: Have you verified that they're doing electrically sensible things, though? (Correct power supplies, correct line voltages, sensible signals on osciliscope)

Comment: is your MSP430 running from a crystal or from an internal oscillator?

Comment: What @pjc50 said - get an oscilloscope or logic analyser on it to see what's happening, there's lots that can go wrong.

Comment: @vicactu From a crystal. Will check with an 'scope when I can.

Comment: Have you tried using 1µ caps?

Comment: @TomL. Not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely sounds like a timing issue. I think your clock is running too fast and instead of bit 7 being sampled, the following stop bit (HIGH) is shifted into the shift register.

Comment: Indeed, it's a timing issue; tinkering with the clock system I was able to get higher speeds. Will have to investigate this deeper.

Comment: Solved by using an external crystal as the clock source.

Comment: could you update the proper working code ?